# ES6 first order functions: find array index of first object with child array that contains a value

Tags: ecmascript-6

I want to make a cool higher-order function chain for what I could do (perhaps more verbosely) like this:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx < collecionA.length; idx++) {
    for (item in collectionA[idx].children) {
        if (item.sku == "someVal") return idx
    }
}
```

Does anyone see a snazzy way to do this with map/find/filter/reduce etc.? I keep wanting to use forEach but then get pwnd when I realize I can't return from it.

Something like:

```
return collectionA.children.findIndex( (child) => child.children.oneOfThemIncludesAnObjectWithThisProperty("someVal"))
```

Comment: That outer for loop appears to be completely superfluous. Is this intentionally?

Comment: Oops, let me edit that... I forgot to put that it's collectionA[idx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) on the outer collection. For each item, iterate the children with [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and check if the value of the property (`sku`) matches the requested value. As soon as a matching value is found, `some` returns `true` immediately, and `findIndex` returns the current index.

```js
const collection = [{"children":[{"sku":"someOtherVal"}]},{"children":[{"sku":"someVal"}]},{"children":[{"sku":"someOtherVal"}]}];

const findIndexWithChildProp = (arr, prop, val) => 
  arr.findIndex(({ children }) => 
    children.some(({ [prop]: v }) => v === val));
    
const result = findIndexWithChildProp(collection, 'sku', 'someVal');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ahh Some! Now that's what I call snazzy. What's this that you're doing in the findIndex callback argument? Is that just destructuring the children prop off of the iterated object?

Comment: I use destructuring to get the property I want to iterate. In this case `{ [prop]: v }` I use destructure a computed property (the value of `prop`), and assign the result to `v`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you are looking for:

```js
function func() {
  var index = -1;
  collectionA.forEach((p, i) => p.children.forEach(item => {
    if (item.sku == "someVal") index = i;
  }));
  return index;
}

var collectionA = [{
  children: [{
    sku: "someOtherVal"
  }]
}, {
  children: [{
    sku: "someVal"
  }]
}, {
  children: [{
    sku: "someOtherVal"
  }]
}]

console.log(func());
```

Comment: Ahh I see, you can use the foreach to set a value and then return that, makes sense.